# How do .NET profilers work?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I am thinking about adding a diagnostics mode build into an app I am writing to count method usage and execution time, similar to what many code profilers like dotTrace do.

I'm having some trouble finding resources through google on how to accomplish this though; obviously it is possible, but can anyone point me to some resources on how I can implement something like method call counts in .NET?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/dotnetprofiler.aspx

Comment: to achieve that you will have to go pretty low level and even use C++ (native) since you will need to hook the .NET runtime itself (see the link from Oded for example)... another option is to use some product (for example SmartAssembly can be configured to build usage reporting into the app) for that kind of thing...

Comment: I believe they basically disassemble the code into IL, then inject various markers after each instruction..  Definitely not trivial to write, but I guess that's why ANTS stuff is so expensive heh.

Comment: Hmm interesting link - I always thought they worked by instrumenting the assembly..

Comment: @MikeChristensen both is possible but more precise and more "official" way is what is shown in that link....

Comment: Is there something specific you want to know about .NET profilers? Asking for a list of resources that explain it isn't really all that useful or what Stack Exchange is good at. Just ask directly about the specific problem you're not understanding.

Comment: @Oded You want to post that link as an answer so I can mark it? That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Mark Trapp I already explained my use case in the question; my primary purpose at the moment is to count method usage and execution time. To be able to ask a more specific question I needed a basic understanding of how these things are accomplished in existing profilers, which I didn't know and was unsuccessful at Googling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Code Project article [Creating a Custom .NET Profiler](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/dotnetprofiler.aspx) describes the process of creating a profiler using the CLR profiler hooks.

This involves creating a COM object that implements the [`ICorProfilerCallback2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230825.aspx) interface and then using environment variables to indicate to the CLR that we wish to profile by using this class:

> When the CLR begins a process, it looks for two environment variables:
>
> - `COR_ENABLE_PROFILING`: This environment variable is set to either 1 or 0. 1 indicates that the CLR should use a profiler. 0 (or the non-existence of this environment variable) indicates that it should not use a profiler.
> - `COR_PROFILER`: Now that we've told the CLR that we want to profile, we have to tell it which profiler to use. Because profilers are implemented as COM objects, this environment variable will be set to the GUID of the coclass that implements the `ICorProfilerCallback2` interface.

Comment: Is it possible to set 2 profilers simultaneously? how to set the COR_PROFILER env variable in order to use two profiler DLLs at the same time

Comment: I doubt it. In particular as the description talks about a single profiler. I suppose you could create a profiler proxy that other profilers could subscribe to, but that's just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am being too simple here, but my solution to this would be logging. Using entlib or log4net and log debug level messages. Then you can just write a little script/program to analyse the log file and give you the method count. There might even be other log diagnostic tools.

Unless you need rich visualization or real time complex relationship mapping etc. Would you need a profiler? For method count and execution time, wouldn't a log file suffice? Once you are in production or don't care about instrumentation you turn your logging level up and forget about those debug messages.

Comment: The problem with logging is having to litter my code with logging calls. Especially if I want to do something like execution time I need to add 3+ lines to every method (timer setup / start, timer stop, log message call) at a minimum. That is pretty messy.

Comment: Agreed. Thats why I would suggest an AOP framework like Spring.Net or PostSharp. AOP is wonderful in its own right, not just for logging. Admittedly I wouldn't add a whole new component to a project just to instrument one method or save 3 lines of code in one place, but if you are using it regularly, then AOP away. The ROI for AOP is quite high and the tipping point at which they should be introduced is quite low, in other words any project that is even mildly complex/professional. In fact, if you are thinking logging, you really should be thinking AOP as well. My 2 cents :-)

Comment: I wasn't aware of PostSharp, thanks for the link. I was planning on using the Enterprise Library 5 for logging, but I was already cringing at the number of method calls cluttering my code.

Comment: "Would you need a profiler? For method count and execution time, wouldn't a log file suffice" That is true, but eventually I would like to be able to do a full CPU time tree rather than just a per method count, which implies knowledge of execution path that would be difficult (but not impossible) to instrument with logs I think.